# How does Flash video content get downloaded, which is specified inside an <embed> tag?

Tags: html, flash, video, embed, firebug

On YouTube Firebug's *Net* panel displays the URL from which the video content is being downloaded and the size of the content keeps growing with the time the video is playing as expected.

But on slashdot.org Firebug does not show the URL of the video content and while the video is playing there is no such request displayed.

The details of the video location is present inside an `<embed>` tag.

**Example:**

http://build.slashdot.org/story/14/11/05/2110250/librarybox-is-an-open-source-server-that-runs-on-low-cost-hardware-video

Related code is:

```
<embed width="640" height="360" align="middle" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" allowscriptaccess="always" loop="false" play="false" name="ooyalaPlayer_16536612_1415221655" bgcolor="#000000" allowfullscreen="true" flashvars="embedCode=8zZ2JqcTqyb68thoGlrCu6rUvM54WQn5&amp;videoPcode=hhMnI6sYpNLKN_o5hP-1TMfZy1Zz" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.swf?embedCode=8zZ2JqcTqyb68thoGlrCu6rUvM54WQn5&amp;version=2">
```

How does the video content get downloaded?

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking at html5 video on youtube ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ['RTMP' stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol), which is consumed directly by the Flash player plug-in. So it's not downloaded as a normal 'HTTP' stream and Firefox - and therefore Firebug - doesn't get any info about that. The params in the `<embed>` code are encrypted, so you cannot get the details of the stream using it.

Comment: What is the name of the software on the image that is visible in your post?

Comment: You mean the soft to get server url and stream name ? because what you see in the image it's a flash video player that I use for my tests on the web.

Comment: NO, the `Flash PLayer` that you mention is a soft (plugin, activex or application) that we use to run and play `SWF` files. Take a look here to know more : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Player. What I said is that I'm using a video player written in `AS3` and executed via `Flash Player` in browsers as a `SWF` file of course.

Comment: ok. If the player is freely available over net could you please share the url link or if are aware of any alternative free player please do mention.

Comment: It's just a simple player that I written to do test, but there are many free flash video player on the net like jwplayer.com, flowplayer.org or github.com/gokercebeci/f4player, ... sometimes you should have some AS skills to use it as you want.